# Xamarin Azure crashes when sending image for OCR analyze

Tags: android, azure, xamarin, ocr

I am using the nuget example for Azure Cognitive services.

The code works fine when sending a sample image as below. But when taking photo and storing it on Android as below it crashes.
Is there any difference in using the paths? Is it somthing with Android access to folder?

Probably something obvious but cannot solve it?!

**urlFile - OK**
urlFile string = https://intelligentkioskstore.blob.core.windows.net/visionapi/suggestedphotos/3.png

**urlFile-Crash**
urlFile string = /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.ocr/files/Pictures/Sample/bild_13.png

**Azure call**
var textHeaders = await client.ReadAsync(urlFile, language: "en");

**Crash text**
Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision.Models.ComputerVisionOcrErrorException: 'Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest''

Comment: the example that crashes is a file path, not a url.  I believe that `ReadAsync` expects you to send it a publicly accessible file url, not a path for a local file that it does not have access to.

Comment: Hi, this is logical answer. Tried another variant due to the example but then it is hanging in the call: var textHeaders = await client.ReadInStreamAsync(File.OpenRead(localFile), language: "en");

Comment: I have solved the issue. But I do not know how! I suspect changing the path string to static helped? Now it is working.